# pass value change event through service in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I've got a property in a service that has a list of booleans that can be changed in the view. When the value changes another component that uses the same service should act on it and refresh data.

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountRequestFilterService {

    public genderFilter: GenderFilter;

    constructor(private rest: RestService) {
        this.genderFilter = new GenderFilter();
    }

    public loadGenders(): Observable<GenderFilter> {
        return this.rest.get("/filter/getgenders")
            .map((result: Response) => this.genderFilter.genders = result.json());
    }
```

Gender filter:

```
export class GenderFilter {

    public genders: FilterItem[] = [];

}
```

Fitter Item:

```
export interface FilterItem {
id: number;
name: string;
show: boolean;
```

}

How can I raise and subscribe on an event from AccountRequestFilterService or subscribe on value change on genderFilter property in the AccountRequestFilterService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your service, please create properties like:

```
private genderSource = new Subject<Array>();
genderSourceObservable = this.genderSource.asObservable();
```

Inside `loadGenders()`:

```
public loadGenders(): Observable<GenderFilter> {
    return this.rest.get("/filter/getgenders")
        .map((result: Response) => {
             this.genderFilter.genders = result.json()
             this.genderSource.next(this.genderFilter.genders);
             return this.genderFilter.genders;
        });
}
```

Then wherever you are using this service... add this code in the `ngOnInit()`

```
this.accountRequestFilterService.genderSourceObservable .subscribe(() => {
     // do whatever you need here..
})
```

> **EDIT: This is extra.. according to a suggestion in comments..**

You can update the Observable inside property setters too. In your case, you have a property `genders`, so making a setter for that doesn't look good to me, but just for completeness, I will add this to the answer..

Say you had a property `_genders` instead of `genders` and you had made a setter for this property.

Something like:

```
set gender(value) {
    // setters could be useful validations.. restricting what value
    // you actually want  to set, etc..
    this._gender = value;
}
```

So you could had updated the Observable in setter, like:

```
set gender(value) {
    this._gender = value;
    this.genderSource.next(this._gender); // or use the getter for gender
}
```

Comment: @user184994: Oh, yeah.. that will be a nice place to do that.. I will update my answer..

Comment: I think it should be new Subject<Array<FilterItem>() and apart from a missed semi colon I managed to let it work. Thanks!

Comment: @WillemdeJong: yeah, right.. I had missed `Array<FilterItem>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use field `EventEmitter<GenderFilter>` and fire event (#emit) everytime you modify that filter. Any entity that is interested in beein notified on filter chage, can subscribe to that emmiter like to any other `Observable`

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter